# Error with IE using ExtJs with Fusioncharts

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs3, fusioncharts

I've upgraded my project from ExtJs 3.2 to 3.4 and now IE 8/9/10 can not render the charts created by Fusioncharts. Everything works just fine on Firefox and Chrome. Upgrading was the only change made to the project. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide a bit more info like what version of FusionCharts are you using, Flash or JS variant, possible code sample/fiddle, etc.